# Remove remote branch locally

Tags: git

I would like to remove remote tracking branches from the local repository, not delete them on the remote. I have fetched all from a remote called `vanilla` so now I have lots of  `remotes/vanilla/<branch_name>`. I would like to remove them from my local repository but I don't want to do any changes on the remote.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
git branch -d -r origin/<remote branch name>
```

This will not delete the branch on the remote repo!

Comment: this tells me `error: branch not found`. I have the branches only in `remotes/vanilla/<branch_name>`. And I can see them only with `git branch -a` command.